# Can't pass data through .bind (JS)

Tags: javascript, function, bind

I need help with passing data through .bind

```
$('#cell1').bind('click',0,function(mx)
{
    alert('hiiii');
    alert(mx[0]);
});
```

There's 'hiii' message appearing, but when it comes to mx[0], array that I'm sure is not empty, 'undefined' appears, what should I do?

Comment: You're "sure" that it's not empty? If you `console.log(mx)`, does it have anything at index 0?

Answer (score 2):

You have to use the `data` attribute of the event argument:

```
$('#cell1').bind('click',0,function(event)
{
    alert('hiiii');
    alert(event.data);
});
```

See http://api.jquery.com/event.data/

Answer (score 0):

In your code, 'mx' is the only argument in function and points to an event object because jQuery. And I see no need to use an argument here.Try this:

```
$('#cell1').bind('click',function(){
    alert('hiiii');
    alert(mx[0]);
});
```

If you want to use 'mx' as an argument for event object.

```
$('#cell1').bind('click',{mx:mx},function(event){
    alert('hiiii');
    alert(event.data.mx[0]);
});
```

Comment: @jantimon  Okay, thank you very much, but I think I didn't clearly explain what I want.  At first: mx is array, that I need to pass through td-click to another function. It's like this: in 'function A' I've got array 'mx', then by click I'm passing 'mx' to 'function B'.  Problem is I can't make this happen, I'm writing 'alert(mx[1])' in 'function  B', and in return I'm getting 'undefined'-message.<br/>My first try was:    $('#cell1').click(function(mx) {alert(mx[i]);Win(mx[i],mx[j]);});  Thanks in advance!